# Store Shipping, Billing & Credit Card Info

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, checkout

I am not sure if this is an appropriate questions for this site - I was just wondering if expresso store automatically saves the user's shipping, billing and credit card details somewhere in the database and at which point (and where) does store save these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store saves the shipping and billing address if they are supplied once the order is submitted. This will show the order details in the CP admin area and you can access it using the `{exp:store:orders}` tags on the front-end. You can see all of the information that store collects about an order by going to the `exp_store_orders` table in the database.

Having said that if you want to link the data the users enters (other then CC details) you will need to goto Store > Settings > Order Fields and link them to either member fields you have created or channel fields you created if you are using Zoo Visitor.

Store does not store any CC details on the server at any point except in some cases. Some gateways will allow you to pass back the last 4 digits of the CC number and the expiration dates.

Some gateways allow you to store the users CC details on their servers then create a token which allows you to pass that to the payment gateway provider and they will charge the card through that. Stripe, PayPal Pro, and Authorize.net are all gateways that pop into mind that allow this kind of functionality but as far as I am aware of none of the Store gateways have this feature is enabled by default so you would need to add that functionality to which ever gateway you were using.